# сколько байт в памяти занимают команды?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Имеется файл листинга (ниже).

> 1. Сколько байт в памяти занимает команда передачи данных MOV?
> 2. Сколько байт в памяти занимает команда выхода из процедуры RET?
> 3. Сколько байт в памяти занимает весь сегмент кода?
> 4. Сколько байт в памяти занимает директива процедуры ENDP?

```
Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1        11/07/12 12:40:29       Page 1
com.asm

  1     0000                         codesg  SEGMENT PARA 'Code'
  2                                    ASSUME  CS:codesg,DS:codesg, SS:codesg, ES:nothing
  3                                    ORG     100H
  4     0100  EB 05 90                 begin: JMP main
  5                                  ;-------------------------------------------------------------
  6     0103  01 02 03 04              flddb  DB     1, 2, 3, 4
  7                                  ;-------------------------------------------------------------
  8     0107                           main   PROC NEAR
  9     0107  8A 26 0103r                MOV    AH,byte ptr flddb
 10     010B  32 F6                      XOR    DH,DH
 11     010D  C3                         RET
 12     010E                           main   ENDP
 13     010E                         codesg  ENDS
 14                                  END     begin

Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1        11/07/12 12:40:29       Page 2
Symbol Table

Symbol Name                       Type   Value

??DATE                            Text   "11/07/12"
??FILENAME                        Text   "com     "
??TIME                            Text   "12:40:29"
??VERSION                         Number 040A
@CPU                              Text   0101H
@CURSEG                           Text   CODESG
@FILENAME                         Text   COM
@WORDSIZE                         Text   2
BEGIN                             Near   CODESG:0100
FLDDB                             Byte   CODESG:0103
MAIN                              Near   CODESG:0107

Groups & Segments                 Bit Size Align  Combine Class

CODESG                            16  010E Para   none    CODE
```

Comment: Если вы знаете английский, то рекомендую к ознакомлению следующие статьи: [Understanding Intel Instruction Sizes](http://www.swansontec.com/sintel.html) (обязательно) и [X86-64 Instruction Encoding](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding) (по желанию).

Comment: И да, вот ещё. Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. **Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить.** Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. **Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.***

Comment: У вас в листинге сначала идет номер строки, потом 4 цифры (16-ричных) адрес, потом группы по 2 цифры - байты команд, потом сами команды. Для примера строка: `4 0100  EB 05 90             begin: JMP main`, в ней команда занимает 3 байта. Также можно определить сколько строка занимает байт по изменению адреса, например `010D - 010B = 2` (в шестнадцатеричной системе).

Comment: С ассемблером дела никогда не имел. У нас была только одна лекция, учусь я на заочке. Задание сделать и не прошу, там задание на 7 листов, которые я сделал сам. Не смог ответить только на один вопрос, который и задал здесь. Программировал только в далеком детстве на Basic и Pascal, 20 лет этим не занимался и не собираюсь.

Comment: "Для примера строка: 4 0100 EB 05 90 begin: JMP main, в ней команда занимает 3 байта". Не понял как считать...

Comment: Если считать по изменению адреса, то у меня получилось: команда MOV = 4 байта, команда RET = 1 байт, весь сегмент = 15 байт, директива процедуры ENDP = 0 байт. Правильно?

Comment: @Toptun, 4 - просто номер строки, 0100 - адрес, EB 05 90 - байты команды в 16-ричном представлении.

Comment: @insolor спасибо! я вроде бы разобрался по второму способу, но первый, честно говоря, так и не понял. "EB 05 90 - байты команды в 16-ричном представлении" - как из этого понять размер? просто уже интересно. Если не сложно, откомментируйте, правильно я посчитал или нет?

Comment: в дополнение к мануалам - посмотрите http://pasm.pis.to/

Comment: @Toptun, все правильно посчитали. Байт - это 8 бит, в 16-ричной системе записывается в виде двух цифр (цифра в 16-ричной системе - символ от 0 до 9 или от A до F). Получается, что 3 группы по 2 цифры (`EB 05 90`) -  это 3 байта.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо еще раз! с системами счисления я знаком и в счете в СС ориентируюсь неплохо. Но я считал по другому: у команды MOV - адрес 0107, у следующей (XOR) - адрес 010B. Между 0107 и 010B разница 4 (байта)

Answer (score 1):

Если считать по изменению адреса, то получается: команда MOV = 4 байта, команда RET = 1 байт, весь сегмент = 15 байт, директива процедуры ENDP = 0 байт.

Answer (score 1):

В целом, как работать с листингом.

Берем строку листинга:

```
9     0107  8A 26 0103r                MOV    AH,byte ptr flddb
```

- `9` - номер строки
- `0107` - смещение (адрес) текущей строки
- `8A 26 0103r` - байты (машинный код), полученные после трансляции команды
- `MOV    AH,byte ptr flddb` - сама команда

В данном случае для меня проще сразу посмотреть количество байт: `8A 26 0103r` - это 8 шестнадцатеричных цифр (`r` не считается), делим на 2 (по две цифры на байт), получаем 4 (1 байт - 8 бит, 1 шестнадцатеричная цифра кодирует 4 бита, отсюда 2 цифры на байт).

Другой способ - смотрим разницу смещений соседних строк. Пример:

```
  9     0107  8A 26 0103r                MOV    AH,byte ptr flddb
 10     010B  32 F6                      XOR    DH,DH
```

Разница `010B - 0107 = 4`, что соответствует тому что мы получили выше, просто посчитав байты. Я считаю, что посчитать байты (если их немного) все-таки проще, чем в уме считать в шестнадцатеричной системе. Но не всегда в листинге присутствует колонка с машинным представлением команд, в таких случаях приходится считать разницу смещений.

Отдельно можно заметить, что первоначально смещение `0000`, а потом вдруг становится `0100`. Это не означает, что какая-то строка занимает `100h` (256) байт, просто директива `ORG 100H` принудительно указывает, что после нее смещение должно стать равно `100h`. Сама по себе директива `org` не занимает в объектном файле нисколько, просто в нем прописывается, что начальное смещение равно `100h`.